# PHP cannot use a scalar as an array warning issue

Tags: php

I have an problem on my website i've made an hits counter :

```
$count = ("hits.txt"); 
$clicks = file($count);
if ($clicks > 5){$clicks = 0;}
$clicks[0]++;
$fp = fopen($count , "w");
fputs($fp , "$clicks[0]");
fclose($fp);
```

but i receive this message : cannot use a scalar as an array warning issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woah - I don't know what's going on in your code here.

- **Why is your string in parenthesises?** *It works, it's just odd*
- **Why do you use brackets on a single-condition-line?** *You can skip the brackets*
- **Why do you have your array in quotes, when it's a variable?** *If it's a variable, don't quote it*
- **Why do you use `file` to read the file instead of a simple file reader?** *Use `fopen`, `file_get_contents` or other solutions to simply read a number off a text file*

Your example could very easily be rewritten to the following:

```
<?php
    $count = (int)file_get_contents("hits.txt");
    file_put_contents("hits.txt", ($count > 10 ? 1 : $count + 1));
?>
```

Comment: Also, include the clicks > 5 , condition.

Comment: $count = (int)file_get_contents("hits.txt");
    if ($count > 10){$count = 1;}
    file_put_contents("hits.txt", $count + 1);

Comment: @checkopenport Check the edit, this will reset it to 1 if it's above 10.